# PHP not downloading CSV to browser

Tags: php

I cannot seem to get the CSV file to download to the browser... There is an SQL query.

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $counter=1;

    // open file and put herder to csv file
    $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($file, array('id','name','test1','test2'));
    // put content to csv file
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        fputcsv($file, array($counter++,$row['name'],
                             ($row['test1']!=-1)?$row['test1']:'null',($row['test2']!=-1)?$row['test2']:'null'));
    }
    $csv_name=(isset($_GET['device'])&&$_GET['device']!='')?$_GET['device']:"all_devices";
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;'.
           'filename='.$csv_name.'_'.date('Y-m-d').'.csv');
}else{
    echo "No device found";
}
```

Comment: What happens when this runs?

Comment: It just displays the sql query into the website

Comment: If your code displays the SQL query, the (main) problem is not in this code.

Comment: Like Scott said, can you please include more of the code? If you're printing out your query, your headers have already been sent, so your definition of headers for `Content-Type` won't work... Plus, there's likely other problems from the sounds of it.

Comment: This is the code only. I don't have any other bits. I have a button that inititates this code and that's it